# save multiple custom views as a single jpeg in android

Tags: android, view, bitmap, save, jpeg

In my app i got three custom views in single activity. So now i need to save it as a single jpeg. How to acheive this. I know how to save one or two bitmaps but this time its three custom views in single activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.wglxy.example.pinchzoompan.PanZoomView
android:id="@+id/zoomview1"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="700dp"
/>
<com.wglxy.example.pinchzoompan.PanZoomView1
android:id="@+id/zoomview2"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="700dp"
/>
<com.wglxy.example.pinchzoompan.PanZoomView2
android:id="@+id/zoomview3"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="700dp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

each view has a picture, now i need to save it as a single jpeg. Can anyone suggest me some ideas.

Comment: You want to make a kind of screenshot of it ? If so, you can look toward a view's drawing cache.

Comment: a single view screenshot can be done with drawing cache, but how to do with multiple views.?

Comment: you can use linearlayout coz the custom views are under LinearLayout

Comment: i did not understand. can we save the linear layout as a jpeg..? if so.please provide some example or etc

Comment: oh thank you.that is the one i needed. linearlayout can be saved as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the my three views saved as a single jpeg file with this code

```
 layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewLayout);
            layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            layout.buildDrawingCache();
            viewbitmap = layout.getDrawingCache(true);
```

and then

```
try {
             viewbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inflate your xml into single view by using layoutinflater then create a bitmap of that view.

Answer (score 0):

just place all child in parent layout then setDrwaingCache  true for that parent view after that whenever you need to take or save all child on that parent view you can getDrawingCache for that parent.